# Where to get world language/nationality list in sql format?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for world language & nationality/ethnic race  list in sql format.
Is there any resource which is importable into MySql ?

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I believe these resources could greatly help more visitors.

The ISO639-3-standard is ridiculously extensive, aiming to to maintain **every single language ever conceived by humankind; spoken, sign, contemporary and extinct alike.** Therefore, the ISO639-2 standard is much more suitable for most cases.

The ISO639-2 standard can be downloaded [here](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/ascii_8bits.html)*.

Regarding demography and ethnicity, [Countrylist.net](http://countrylist.net) has great resources for all of those, from a geographical basis. I use this list a lot in my projects.

* The lists are pipe-separated, so they're not SQL as you requested, but can easily be imported thus:

```
-- Create table to hold the data.
create table language (
  id int(5) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  bibliographical char(3) not null,
  terminological char(3) default null,
  alpha2 char(2) default null,
  name_en varchar(80) not null,
  name_fr varchar(80) not null
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;

-- Fill the table with the ISO-639-2 data.
load data local infile "ISO-639-2_8859-1.txt" into table language fields terminated by "|" (bibliographical, terminological, alpha2, name_en, name_fr);
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/download.asp

With samples of `CREATE TABLE` statements.

To import a tab-delimited sheet into `MySQL`, use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).